# Error from Singularity building a docker image . Process gets killed

Tags: docker, build, slurm, hpc, singularity-container

The process gets killed every time I run a singularity build for an 8GB docker image in a HPC

Initially I would run
`salloc --time=1:0:0 --ntasks=4 --gres=gpu:2 --account=<xx> --nodes=2 --ntasks-per-node=2`

then `singularity build myimage.sif docker-archive://myimage.tar`
Then towards the ending of my build, I would get

```
FATAL:   While performing build: while creating squashfs: create command failed: signal: killed:
```

Since I thought it was a memory issue,I  did increase the size to
`salloc --time=1:0:0 --ntasks=4 --gres=gpu:4 --account=<xx> --nodes=4 --ntasks-per-node=1`

I'll rerun the build command and the process gets killed right away. As shown in the the logs below  As if there isn't enough no space left in some temp memory somewhere

````
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob b43408d5f11b [============================>---------] 48.0MiB / 62.6MiB
Copying blob 23135df75b44 done  
Copying blob fe6d8881187d done  
Copying blob 44baf5c75672 [=====>--------------------------------] 7.0MiB / 43.6MiB
Killed```
````

Comment: singularity /apptainer recommends superuser permission to build an image. Use your local machine. https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/build_a_container.html

Comment: I just get the same error on a Kubernetes cluster and in my case Singularity is killed because it tries to allocate too much memory. Adding more memory in the resources fixed the problem.